# How would I prove that f is onto then gcd(m,n) = 1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm having trouble getting started on this question:

Define f: ℤn → ℤn by f(x) = mx mod n. Use the Bézout’s theorem to prove that if f is onto, then gcd(m,n)=1.

Comment: I have only an approach without Bezout : If $p$ divides both $m$ and $n$, then we can show that $mx\mod n$ must be divisible by $p$ , hence the map cannot be onto.

Comment: What universe does $x$ live in?  And for that matter, what world do m, n live in??

Comment: @Peter only if m, n, x are all integers.  Please point out where the OP gives the domain of m, n, x?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is onto then there is some $a$ for which $f(a) = 1$ which is to say $ma = 1 \mod n$. This means that there is some $k$ such that $ma = kn + 1$. Let $d = \gcd(m, n)$. Then $(d|m \land d|n) \implies (d|ma \land d|kn) \implies d|(ma - kn) \implies d|1 \implies d = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = mx\equiv k\pmod n$ then $n|mx -k$.  As $\gcd(n,m)|n$ then $\gcd(n,m)|mx-k$.  And as $\gcd(n,m)|m$ then $\gcd(n,m)|k$.  So $f(x)$ can only be equivalent to multiples of $\gcd(n,m)$.

If *any* $k$ exist that are not multiples of $\gcd(m,n)$ then $f(x) \equiv k \pmod n$ will be impossible and $f$ can not be onto. Now $k\equiv 1$ or $k\equiv n-1$ will be relatively prime to $n$ so $\gcd(m,n)|k$ can only happen if $\gcd(m,n) =1$.

.......

So that was the brainstorm.

Here's the prooof.

If $\gcd(m,n) =1$ then there exist $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ so that $am + bn =1$. (By Bezout.)  Thus for any $k$ we have $kam + kbn = k$ and $kam = k-kbn$ so $f(ka)\equiv k \pmod n$ and $f$ is onto.

If $f$ is onto then there exists an $a$ so that $f(a)=ma \equiv 1 \pmod n$.  That is there exist a $b \in \mathbb Z$ so that $am = 1 + bn$ so $am -bn =1$.  So by Bezout's Lemma $\gcd(m,n) =1$.